# Why is the zero polynomial the only one to have infinite roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

How can it be that the zero polynomial ($f(x)=0$) is the only polynomial which has an infinite number of roots? As stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial):

> The polynomial $0$, which may be considered to have no terms at all, is called the zero polynomial. Unlike other constant polynomials, its degree is not zero. Rather the degree of the zero polynomial is either left explicitly undefined, or defined as negative (either $−1$ or $−∞$). These conventions are useful when defining Euclidean division of polynomials. The zero polynomial is also unique in that it is the only polynomial having an infinite number of roots. The graph of the zero polynomial, $f(x) = 0$, is the $x$-axis.

We can have the polynomial $x-y$ to have infinitely many roots: $x=y=\text{all real numbers}$.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: $\sin x$ has infinite roots of 0

Comment: @Arjang $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer if you write it as taylor series then it is.

Comment: @Arjang As a power series, it has infinitely many terms. A polynomial has only finitely many terms. Therefore, still not a polynomial.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer reference please, where does it says polynomial must have finitely many terms.

Comment: @Arjang https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial "a polynomial can either be zero or can be written as the sum of a finite number of non-zero terms. Each term consists of the product of a number—called the coefficient of the term[2]—and a finite number of indeterminates, raised to nonnegative integer powers."

Comment: Further in every formulation of polynomials, at least univariate ones, you'll see them in the form

$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + a_n x^n$$

Notice how this has a finite stopping point - the $x^n$ term. That alone should be a sufficient clue that a polynomial *must* have, by definition, finitely many terms (the above $f$ has $n+1$).

Comment: Actually even a (non-zero) single variable polynomial can have infinitely many roots. The polynomial $x^2+1$ has infinitely many zeros *in the ring of quaternions*. The proper formulation of the result is that the number of zeros of a non-zero single variable polynomial can have *in a field* is bounded by its degree.

Comment: The question has a complex history. Yet at this point, e.g., OP account deleted, I think we should move past this. The question is based on a simple but arguably plausible confusion. It also seems clear enough what the question is. It does not seem impossible that somebody else might face this problem. Thus I reopened this post now. If somebody wants to discuss this further ask me in chat or post on meta.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No, the proper formulation is that -- over a commutative ring $R$ --   nonzero univariate polynomials have no more roots than their degree $\iff R$ is a domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that the statement you quote is ok, but it omits that it is only about polynomials of **a single variable**. For polynomials of several variables the statement is not true and you gave a good counterexample $P(x,y) = x-y$.

Actually, the study of the "roots" of polynomials of several variables is a huge field (the respective sets of roots are called "varieties" and they are studied in algebraic geometry).

Comment: First of all for a zero polynomial there is no such thing defined as in single variable or in multiple variable just like it's degree, a zero polynomial is a zero polynomial

Comment: I'd say that "zero polynomial" is ambiguous as is does not specify the number of variables. (In the same way, terms like "identity" or "zero function" are ambiguous.)

Comment: Moreover, I find the Wikipedia article about polynomials quite confusing. As the article treats polynomials of several variables from the start, the quote is plain wrong in the context.

Answer (score 1):

The result in question is only about *single-variable* polynomials (hence the reference to "$f(x)$").  As $p(x,y)=x-y$ shows, a polynomial in more than one variable can indeed have infinitely many zeroes without being the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial in a single variable can have only finite number of roots unless it is identically $0$.
This does not extend to polynomials in several variables as your example shows.

Comment: But zero can't be classified to have single or more variable, just like it's degree

Comment: @user629353 You are simply misquoting a result without verifying the definitions and posting too many comments. You will not a better answer than the one's already available.

Comment: @ kavi Rama Please show a single web page or a single book page written that zero is a multivariate or univariate polynomial. Have you?